# The Convert class and converting Console input C#

Tags: c#

This question is more of a "Why can't I do this/What am I doing wrong" as I have managed to accomplish what the program should do, but it raised more questions around why certain things work the way they do.

For starters, the goal of this project is to capture a single character from the Console window (using Console.Read()/.ReadLine()), convert it to a string with the Convert class, and then write it to the Console window.

I've managed to get my project to have this functionality with the following code:

```
namespace ReadConvertWrite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String input = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(input);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Given that this seems like a pointless exercise since the conversion is unnecessary I wanted to make it necessary by using the .Read() method instead of .ReadLine(). Which leads me to my question:

Why is it that .Read() always prints the hexadecimal value of the character inputted into the console despite the MSDN documentation making it sound like .Read() and .ReadLine() work the same way apart from reading a single character Vs a line, and beyond that why do none of the Convert class methods I've tried (.ToInt, .ToString, etc) work to actually give me output other than the hexadecimal values?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
namespace ReadConvertWrite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Console.Read()));
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
namespace ReadConvertWrite
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = 0;
            input = Console.Read();
            String InputString = Convert.ToString(input);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the docs say the `Read` is the same as `ReadLine`?

Comment: Just wanted to say good on you for asking the question, says a lot that you care not just that something works, but that you know *how* it works.

Comment: var InputString = Convert.ToChar(input).ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.Read` returns an integer representing a character. `Console.ReadLine` returns a string.

When you do `Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine())`, you're simply echoing your input. When you do `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Console.Read()))`, you're taking the numeric value of the character and printing it as a number.

`Convert.ToString(int)` will not interpret the integer as a character - that would be rather ridiculous. Would you expect `Convert.ToString(42)` to print `*`? You need to cast the integer to a character instead:

```
Console.WriteLine((char)Console.Read());
```

Most likely, you don't want to use `Console.Read` anyway - it's a rather specific thing dealing with old-school CLI, rather than anything very useful for a typical console program, unless you need to stream lots of characters and want to avoid allocating huge strings unnecessarily.

Make sure to handle end-of-file correctly - `Console.Read()` will return `-1` when the input stream ends, which is not a valid value for `char`.

Answer (score 2):

If you hover your mouse over Read() it will show you it returns an int, not a string. Converting an 'int' to a string will just be a string representation of an int. To get a character from an int, cast it back to a char.

The cast to a char will convert the number back into its character representation.

```
Console.WriteLine((char)Console.Read());
```